# the meaning of "partially"

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, adverbs, ielts

Here is a test I found on the website below
https://ieltsonlinetests.com/ielts-mock-test-2023-march-reading-practice-test-3?mode=practice_test&parts=1&duration=120
There is a question I don't understand.
The question requires me to answer if the following statement agrees with the information given in Reading Passage:

> The willingness for Kazakhstan to take the restoration action to save
> the Small Aral Sea is somehow not certain.

the information mentioned by the question is:

> Kazakhstan has nonetheless tried to partially restore the
> northern Aral.

then the answer is **True**.

but why?
I thought the meaning of "partially" in the information was not complete restorations.
In other words, Kazakhstan wants to restore the northern Aral.
but for some reason, they can only restore some northern Aral, not fully restore it.

Can I understand it this way?

Comment: It's a stupid test. Just because Kazakhstan has made *some efforts* to restore "the northern Aral" gives us no idea whether they did that ***willingly***. All we know is that they ***tried*** to do something (from the text here, we don't even know if they had any success at all). And I'm no geographer, but Wikipedia tells me that "Small Aral Sea", "Lesser Aral Sea", and "the northern Aral" all refer to the same place (as distinct from "South Aral Sea", "the Greater Sea", "Large Aral Sea"). Without Wikipedia, I wouldn't have known that, and thus wouldn't understand the actual question anyway.

Comment: People can’t read the question without creating an account on that site. It would be helpful to have a larger extract of the text around the sentence mentioned by the answer key. I think this question is about understanding “nonetheless”.